# Django template for loop returning empty list

Tags: django, list, for-loop, django-templates

Iam trying to parse html page and find all image tags and display it in django template

**view**

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.flipkart.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tags=soup.findAll('img')
template = get_template('welcome.html')            
variables = RequestContext(request,{'tags':tags})
output = template.render(variables)
return HttpResponse(output)
```

**Template**

```
{% block content %} 

<div class="row">
 <ul class="thumbnails">
 {% for row in tags %}
 <li >
   <span>Flash</span>
   <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
   {{ row }}
   </a>
</li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

i printed tags

```
 [<img src="http://passets-cdn.pinterest.com/images/search.gif" alt="" />, <img        src="http://media-cache2.pinterest.com/upload/422281184577033_NvxwzARh_b.jpg"  alt="#wedding #bouquet #flowers" class="PinImageImg" style="height: 288px;" />, <img src="http://media-cache0.pinterest.com/avatars/heygirlfriend-33.jpg" alt="Profile picture of Heather Carpenter" />, <img src="http://media-cache2.pinterest.com/avatars/lilizzy08_1330284092.jpg" class="profile user_image" alt="Profile picture of JoAnn Boyle Barker" />, <img src="http://media-cache2.pinterest.com/avatars/camelotparty_1330114747.jpg" class="profile user_image" alt="Profile picture of Camelot Party" />, <img src="http://media-cache5.pinterest.com/avatars/mamababe13_1327965590.jpg" class="profile user_image" alt="Profile picture of Irene Hardin Sanchez" />, <img src="http://media-cache5.pinterest.com/avatars/mpowers213_1333304368.jpg" class="profile user_image" alt="Profile picture of Maggie Powers" />, <img src="http://media-cache7.pinterest.com/avatars/apricot1026_1334529181.jpg" class="profile user_image" alt="Profile picture of Michelle Nadel" />, <img src="http://media-cache4.pinterest.com/upload/169025792234929326_WtMMM67J_b.jpg" alt="Dr. Oz Metabolism Booster" class="PinImageImg" style="height: 256px;" />, <img src="http://media-cache6.pinterest.com/avatars/karenmigala_1332630951.jpg" alt="Profile picture of Karen Migala" />, <img src="http://media-cache9.pinterest.com/avatars/dutchjohnson-26.jpg" class="profile user_image" alt="Profile picture of Dutch Johnson" />]
```

when i tried to print the tags there is lot of img tags, But iam getting an empty list in browser(when displayed).

`HTML page Displays`

multple empty lists like [] [] [] [] [] []

`Rendered Content`

```
<li >
<span>Flash</span>
<a href="#" class="thumbnail">
[]

</a>
</li>

 <li >
 <span>Flash</span>
 <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
 []

</a>
</li>

 <li >
 <span>Flash</span>
 <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
 []

 </a>
 </li>
 <li >
<span>Flash</span>
 <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
 [] 
</a>
</li>
 <li >
 <span>Flash</span>
 <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
 []  
</a>
</li>
```

Please help

Comment: 1) Post content of tags variable from debugger after line tags=soup.findAll('img') 2) Post content of rendered html page (part inside <div class="row")

Comment: I had posted the necessary contents

Comment: Also put rendered content in `output`

Answer (score 3):

Ah, that's because the `Tag` of BeautifulSoup is callable, thus Django template invoke it directly

```
class Tag(PageElement):
    ...
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Calling a tag like a function is the same as calling its
        findAll() method. Eg. tag('a') returns a list of all the A tags
        found within this tag."""
        return apply(self.findAll, args, kwargs)
```

For newer version of Django, you could set `do_not_call_in_templates` to True to avoid invoking.

```
from BeautifulSoup import Tag

tags=soup.findAll('img')
Tag.do_not_call_in_templates = True
# render
```